# call the subroutine of the shell script from perl script and pass certain parameters to it

Tags: perl, shell, unix

How can i call the subroutine of the shell script and pass certain parameters to it? something like below ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
### need something like this
source file.sh
routine;            # <-- this is supposed to be part of file.sh which is called 
                    # from perl script and some parameter are passed to it
```

Comment: this could be a **[XYProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)** ... are you sure you need to do *this* exactly in this way? What is the underlying need you need to adress?

Answer (score 1):

No.  They are two different languages.  All you can do is call a shell script from Perl as a child process, using, for example, `system()` or `qx()`.

Write your program in one language, Perl or shell, don't try to mix them.

OK, it is *possible* to export a function from a shell and then parse and execute it in Perl, but it is a lot of work, insecure, and usually not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

A hack around this problem would be to isolate the content of routine out of file.sh into subfile.sh - then you can do this in Perl:

```
@cmdargs=('subfile.sh', $arg1, "arg2");
system(@cmdargs);
```

The first list element is the command, the second the value of a Perl variable being passed as an argument to subfile.sh; the third is a literal being passed as an argument to subfile.sh.

Avoid maintenance issues between the copy of routine's contents in subfile.sh and file.sh by writing a wrapper for subfile.sh in file.sh and simply call it with the appropriate arguments, like any other shell command, wherever you're calling routine in file.sh.

I think that would work.